# Application of the implicit function to the unit matrix

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, implicit-function-theorem

The task is to show that there's such environment $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n,n}$ in the surroundings of unit matrix $I_n$ that for any $X\in U$ there can be found a matrix $Y\in \mathbb{R}^{n,n}$ that satisfies $X^{p}=Y^{q}$ ($q,p\in \mathbb{N}$ here)

Now we have to prove this one by using the implicit function theorem and I have no clue how to identify some "matrix building function" with a map $ \mathbb{R}^n×\mathbb{R}^m \mapsto \mathbb{R}^m$ which is required for the theorem to be applied. I tried but I cannot seem to get the dimensions to correspond with the theorem.

Id be grateful for any hint)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let $f: \Bbb R^{n \times n} \times \Bbb R^{n \times n} \to \Bbb R^{n \times n}$ be the map defined by
$$
f(X,Y) = X^p - Y^q.
$$
We wish to prove that there is a function $g$ such that $Y = g(X)$ is a matrix for which $f(X,Y) = 0$ whenever $X$ in some neighborhood of $I$. Begin by noting that $F(I,I) = 0$.

---

Regarding the invertibility of the derivative requirement: recall that the derivative of $f$ with respect to $Y$ must be invertible. Computing and considering the derivative of a function with matrix inputs is tricky. One approach is as follows: expanding $f(I,I+H)$ yields
$$
f(X,Y+H) = I^p - (I + H)^q =\\
I - I-\binom q1 H^1 - \binom q2 H^2 - \cdots = 
-qH + o(H).
$$
Thus, the derivative $D_Y f(X,Y)$ at the point $X = I, Y = I$ is the linear map
$$
D_Y f(X,Y)(H) = -qH.
$$
This linear map is inverible.

Comment: Dont we have to prove first $f(X,Y)=0$ for whatever X,Y und that $Df(X,Y)$ is reversible? Im really confused here

Comment: It is obviously not true that $f(X,Y) = 0$ for all choices of $X,Y$. Analogously, if we wanted to show the existence of the function $g(x) = \sqrt{x}$, we would consider the function $f(x,y) = x - y^2$, but it is obviously not true that $f(x,y) = 0$ for all choices of $x,y$.

Comment: @piercetodsteltzer Also, what do you mean by $Df(X,Y)$? Please be more precise.

Comment: Sorry, it was dumb phrased cuz I didn't really know what I was saying. Im just uncertain where to start. We want to show there's such $g $ that $g(X)=Y$ if X is in neighbourhood $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ of $I_n$. For that must be valid $f(X_0,Y_0)=0$ and $D_{Y}f(X_0,Y_0)$ should be invertible. Since $X\subset U$ we put $I_n$ in $f$. If $f(I_n,Y_0)=0$ is to be , then $Y_0=I_n$ is the only choice. Then $D_{Y}f(X_0,Y_0)=-q{I_n}^{q-1}$  is obviously invertible but now Y must also be in $I_n$ neighbourhood, whereas we have to prove the statement for $Y\subset \mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: $X_0,Y_0$ are matrices in neighbourhood of which we look for X,Y with $X^p=Y^q$(☆). So $X_0=I_n$ but Im not sure about $Y_0$ since $Y$ has to be just some random matrix from $\mathbb{R}^n$ that satisfies (☆). But according to the theorem there must be some neighbourhood of $Y_0$ ,so ...

Comment: It is incorrect to say that $D_Yf(X_0,Y_0) = -q I_n^{q-1}$. In particular, it doesn't make sense to say that $D_Yf(X_0,Y_0)$ is a matrix whose size is the same as that of $Y$.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you're trying to say about $Y$. I suggest that you review what exactly the implicit function theorem says.

Comment: @piercetodsteltzer Also, it would probably be easier to add any followup questions to your original post instead of trying to type everything out in the comments here